# Implement a function StrSep(s, sub, part1, part2) to receive a string (s) and a substring (sub) and return :

Tags: c++

**part1:** the part of (s) preceding but not including ( sub)
**part2:** the part of ( s) succeeding but not including (sub)

For example, if s = “3rdofJuly”, sub = “of”, then part1= “3rd” and part2 = “July”

If (sub) does not exist in (s), then part1, part2 are returned as Null strings.

this is what i came up with for my code, i managed to do part1 but i can't get part2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;
void StrStep (string,string);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string S;
    string Sub = "of";

    cout << "enter a string : " <<endl;
    cin >> S;
    StrStep(S,Sub);
    return 0;
}


void StrStep (string &s, string &sub)
{
    string part1;
    string part2;
    if (s.find(sub) != string::npos )
        part1 = s.erase(s.find(sub),string::npos);
    if (s.find(sub) != string::npos)
        part2 = s.erase(

}
```

Comment: The code succeeding, but not including `part2 = s.erase(` is missing.

Comment: @Muscampester yeah i have no idea how to do this part, i tried so many things and nothing works, this is the part i need help with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::string::find` method returns the *starting* position of the search string.

To get to the end of the search string, you need to add the length of the substring to the position:

```
std::string::size_type position = s.find(sub) + sub.length();
```

You will need to check if the `position` is still within the string.  There is a Use Case where the *part2* may be empty.